# Laravel Passport - Client based token (not user based)

Tags: laravel-5, oauth-2.0, api-key, laravel-passport

I am trying to implement Laravel Passport in order to allow 3rd party applications to connect to our API.

The ideal workflow is this:

1. Users login to their CMS and create an API Key.
2. Once created, they can connect a 3rd party app to the CMS e.g. mobile app, e-commerce, lead generation forms, etc.
3. No OAuth dialog should be displayed - once an API Key has been generated it should be the only step in the process to accessing the data. In fact, no login is needed (username/password) at all - just the API Key.

I am new to OAuth and Laravel Passport and have the following questions:

1. Is Laravel Passport the right way to go for the above scenario? or
   should I implement a different approach (i.e take advantage of
   Laravel multi auth support or a JWT approach).
2. A token seems to be dependent on a user. In my scenario it does not
   fit the workflow/logic. A token must be connected to an app/client only. Is
   there a way to support this?
3. It seems as there is something called personal access clients - which may skip the login process, will that be good way to go? If so - what will be the quickest workflow to allow 3rd party access using the API key (do they need to call an initial `/authorize` route or simply attach the token to the calls).

Your insights are much appreciated!

Comment: I am looking for the same, but the laravel version is 8. @dev7 did you find any solution ?